# How can I train build orders with increased delay?

Tags: starcraft-2

Usually I train my build orders in a controlled environment, this means: Single Player vs Very Easy AI on Faster speed. This way I have nearly no fights against my opponent.

The problem is that the lag or delay is nearly optimal. Starcraft 2 has always a slight delay of around 200 ms, but if you play on ladder the lag increases, sometimes it is almost unbearable.

I struggle with this as everything seems off. This usually means:

- I queue a command more often, because I think I missed the key. Instead of pressing 1,s I enter 1,s,s,s,ESC,ESC.
- I do not issue commands because I misclick and forget to check. Initially it looks ok because of the delay as I do not expect an immediate response. (e.g. I click 0,w to get +1 which is wrong. It should be 0,e)
- Micro is ridiculously hard compared to my normal training environment. (e.g. my current Stutter Step relies on reacting to what my Marines currently do, this does not work with lag, sometimes my Marines do not even shoot because I click too fast)

In addition to the stress of a normal ladder game I feel uneasy about my execution.

So how can I simulate this kind of delay in a training game? I want to be able to execute my Build Order without much Micro, so I get my timings right.

Currently my best approach is to open a random 2v2 game and play with 3 bronze players. This works, but I often have to restart because someone drops or leaves. Sometimes my ally takes the only natural and I have to go another build.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I *think* that creating a custom multiplayer game with you and a few AIs will introduce lag.

Comment: This is true, but you will get the optimal lag (100-200 ms). I thought of something like 350+ ms because those are the games I struggle the most with.

Comment: Have you tried just playing custom maps in multiplayer 1v1 against a computer?

Comment: Are you sure your not experiencing FPS lag? Also, have you tried a better connection. The only reason I ask, is that a latency with Blizzard has never been a direct problem of me failing a build order. I'm Masters Zerg and playing on the ladder shows me no difference when playing on the ladder; that is related to timings and build orders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to play a single player game to practice a build order. You may, however, want to look at the arquade games such as build order tester, etc. In this way you can practice your initial build order without an AI opponent and should get some lag from the game not being completely local. While you may not experience all the same lag, it is the best result you will get. Otherwise, just practice on the ladder. The best way you will learn is not in a controlled environment.

Comment: I guess there is no better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make 2v2 computers ? You'll have an ally and correct environement without having any stress. And if you choose some pretty easy computers, you wont have a chance to loose and being insulted by the random player because you were just crushed cause of you. That is the best thing I can think about...

Comment: What does this have to do with dealing with lag? It works for the stress thing, but that's only a secondary issue.

Comment: Playing 2v2 computers is not performed locally as you have an ally. Then, you should have the same lag than when doing 1v1. I cannot imagine why you would have larger lag in a 1v1 game than in a 2v2 computers. One other player of the internet in each game.

Comment: Ah, you mean adding a player ally. Got it.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't need to do your build orders differently with lag. The only time lag should matter is in the case of intense micro, like stutter-step. The lag shouldn't throw off the timings of your build order, since your build order should be based on supply and doing things in a certain order. I think rather than practicing your build order with lag, you should practice:

- Not pressing the same button multiple times when you don't need to
- Not misclicking

I don't know how you're thinking of compensating when you practice in a laggier environment, but I'm pretty sure that's the wrong approach.